# How do I interact with selected NPC without clicking?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How to interact with selected NPC without clicking? If I were to use `/tar Joe Blow` what do I do next to start talking to him? This will help many people who trying to turn in quests and get quests from NPCs that are covered by players and their big mounts.

Comment: If you're dealing with crowding, you can also turn on NPC name plates ("V" by default") and right-click the name plate of the NPC you want to interact with. You still need the mouse for this though, obviously.

Comment: Right, I know what referring too. However, problem with this is when the show name plates are displayed, the plates move to fast to click on. Which means I click miss or worst I start attacking someone by mistake.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It doesn't seem a player is able to interact with a NPC via a macro. However, one can interact with a NPC via a built in key binding.

Set up key binding to interact with target:

- Open up the **Game Menu**
- Select **Key Bindings**
- Scroll though the list to **Interact With Target** under the *Targeting Functions* heading
- Click **Not Bound**
- Enter the key you want it bind to (example <kbd>F6</kbd>)
- Click **OKAY**

***Test It**: Select an NPC and push the key you set as the binding key.*

***Update**: Little over a week after this answer was posted, AOL's WoW Insider release an article about this subject. Here is a link to WoW Insider's ["Interact with target keybind gets you past players atop NPCs."](http://wow.joystiq.com/2010/12/15/interact-with-target-keybind-gets-you-past-players-atop-npcs/)*

Comment: Though technically, after rebinding the key, it's very easy to make a macro to do so :P

Comment: ... Technically speaking...

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way.  My suggestion is to use the "." key, as that is easy to remember and not bound to anything else by default.

Comment: just saved me and 40 of my guidies (Armada, Jerry)